# Font not Displaying correctly in Reporting service

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, rdlc

in report service some fonts are not displaying english fonts are correct but problem in displaying other fonts why is it so. this problem is seen in windows xp only in windows 7 it is working properly

[image: Report Preview]

Comment: i think you don't have that font in your Windows XP.

Comment: What do you mean "other fonts"? Do you really mean, "other languages"? If so, can the Windows XP system display any text in that language in any application?

Comment: Thanks, but that only answered the first part of my question. Can the Windows system use the south indian font in Notepad, Word or other applications? If no, then the font is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the rendering extensions in Reporting Services are actually rendered on the client machine. If the font isn't actually installed on the client machine, then the report will not show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the data field font type in the report.